# MATLAB Cell Array - Average two values if another column matches

Tags: matlab, average, cell-array

I have a cell array in which some of the entries have two data points. I want to average the two data points if the data were collected on the same day.

The first column of cell array 'site' is the date. The fourth column is the data concentration. I want to average the fourth column if the data comes from the same day.

For example, if my cell array looks like this:

```
01/01/2011  36-061-0069   1   10.4
01/01/2011  36-061-0069   2   10.1
01/04/2011  36-061-0069   1   7.9
01/05/2011  36-061-0069   1   13
```

I want to average the fourth column (10.4 and 10.1) into one row and leave everything else the same.

Help? Would an if elseif loop work? I'm not sure how to approach this issue, especially since cell arrays work a little differently than matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it succinctly without a loop, using a combination of `unique`, `diff` and `accumarray`.

Define data:

```
data = {'01/01/2011'  '36-061-0069'  '1'  '10.4';
        '01/01/2011'  '36-061-0069'  '2'  '10.1';
        '01/04/2011'  '36-061-0069'  '1'  '7.9';
        '01/05/2011'  '36-061-0069'  '1'  '13'};
```

Then:

```
dates = datenum(data(:,1),2); % mm/dd/yyyy format. Change "2" for other formats
[dates_sort ind_sort] = sort(dates);
[~, ii, jj] = unique(dates_sort);
n = diff([0; ii]);
result = accumarray(jj,vertcat(str2double(data(ind_sort,4))))./n;
```

gives the desired result:

```
result =

   10.2500
    7.9000
   13.0000
```

If needed, you can get the non-repeated, sorted dates with `data(ind_sort(ii),1)`.

Explanation of the code: the dates are first converted to numbers and sorted. The unique dates and repeated dates are then extracted. Finally, data in repeated rows are summed and divided by the number of repetitions to obtain the averages.

**Compatibility issues for Matlab 2013a onwards**:

The function `unique` has [changed](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) in Matlab 2013a. For that version onwards, add `'legacy'` flag to `unique`, i.e. replace the line `[~, ii, jj] = unique(dates_sort)` by

```
[~, ii, jj] = unique(dates_sort,'legacy')
```

Comment: What does ii and jj refer to? I've been trying to use your code since it seems to be exactly what I need, but I'm not able to do vertcat because my ii and jj are now different lengths. ii and n are the same length while jj is longer. My data array doesn't have the quotes (''). Don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: It's normal that ii and jj have different lengths. ii contains the date indices without repetitions, and jj contains all dates indicating which are repeated. Which error do you get? And how can you data not have the quotes? Isn't it a cell array with strings in the first two columns?

Comment: @user2258883 Another thing: which Matlab version do do you use? Tray changing `~` by a dummy variable name such as `aux`

Comment: I use MATLAB 2012 and the error I get is 'Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.' Using aux still gave the same error.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what is your cell array? What does it contain in its first column? Or better, what is the result of typing `whos data` (where `data` is the name of your cell array)?

Comment: Name        Size             Bytes  Class    Attributes

  data      232x4             115574  cell

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the date strings don't all have the same width. I have updated the solution (changed first line); try now

Comment: Sorry! I wasn't on MATLAB over the weekend. I tried the updated solution and now it says 'Error using ==> vertcat, CAT argument dimensions are not consistent'

Comment: Can you post a link to an example cell array (saved as a .mat file)?

Comment: I have two files here - the long named one is the one with all the data. 'data' is the file with only columns 1 through 4 because I wanted to make it match with the script you wrote. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/li3hh1nvt11vok5/4YGfwStQlo

Comment: There were two problems with my answer: your last column is strings, not numbers as I thought; and the dates are not sorted. I think it works now, see updated solution. I have tested with your "data.mat" file. Your date format is "mm/dd/yyyy", right?

Comment: Thank you so much! It is working now. I didn't realize the last column was strings. I actually used another line of code to sort it, but incorporating it into this code seems more efficient.

Comment: Great! We finally made it! :-)

Comment: @user2258883 I don't have the `read_mixed_csv` function or know the `netcdf` format... sorry!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do :

```
for it = 1:size(CellArray,1)
   sum = sum + cellArray{it}(4) % or .NameOfColumn if it a cell containing struct
end

mean(sum)
```

Comment: It gives me an error saying 'Error using sum, Not enough input arguments'.

Comment: Also, I don't want to find the mean of the entire 4th column. I only want to find the average of the rows where the first column (date) matches. Everything needs to be left alone.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw that. But the LuisMendo answer seems to be good.