# Matlab matching first column of a row as index and then averaging all columns in that row

Tags: matlab, matrix, average, matching, mean

I need help with taking the following data which is organized in a large matrix and averaging all of the values that have a matching ID (index) and outputting another matrix with just the ID and the averaged value that trail it.

```
File with data format:
(This is the StarData variable)
ID>>>>Values

002141865 3.867144e-03  742.000000  0.001121  16.155089  6.297494  0.001677

002141865 5.429278e-03  1940.000000  0.000477  16.583748  11.945627  0.001622

002141865 4.360715e-03  1897.000000  0.000667  16.863406  13.438383  0.001460

002141865 3.972467e-03  2127.000000  0.000459  16.103060  21.966853  0.001196

002141865 8.542932e-03  2094.000000  0.000421  17.452007  18.067214  0.002490
```

Do not be mislead by the examples I posted, that first number is repeated for about 15 lines then the ID changes and that goes for an entire set of different ID's, then they are repeated as a whole group again, think first block of code = [1 2 3; 1 5 9; 2 5 7; 2 4 6] then the code repeats with different values for the columns except for the index. The main difference is the values trailing the ID which I need to average out in matlab and output a clean matrix with only one of each ID fully averaged for all occurrences of that ID.
Thanks for any help given.

Comment: ID is first column? And for matching ID's, do you want to average a given column, or all of them?

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056905/matlab-cell-array-average-two-values-if-another-column-matches

Comment: I have seen the question you posted but I am looking for the average of all of the columns and every time I try to use acummarray I cannot get it to average all of the columns for me, just a single one

Comment: So for each ID you want a single value, with the average of all columns for those selected rows?

Comment: If Im understanding correctly then yes, except I need the average for each column, not just a single value for all of the columns; so I would need the second column in my final result to be an average of everything in the second column and so on for all of the columns.

Comment: Ok. Got it. A modification of my previous answer wiil do. I'm posting it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modification of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19057516/2586922) does the job, as follows:

```
[value_sort ind_sort] = sort(StarData(:,1));
[~, ii, jj] = unique(value_sort);
n = diff([0; ii]);
averages = NaN(length(n),size(StarData,2)); % preallocate
averages(:,1) = StarData(ii,1);
for col = 2:size(StarData,2)
  averages(:,col) = accumarray(jj,StarData(ind_sort,col))./n;
end
```

The result is in variable `averages`. Its first column contains the values used as indices, and each subsequent column contains the average for that column according to the index value.

**Compatibility issues for Matlab 2013a onwards**:

The function `unique` has [changed](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) in Matlab 2013a. For that version onwards, add `'legacy'` flag to `unique`, i.e. replace second line by

```
[~, ii, jj] = unique(value_sort,'legacy')
```

Comment: Hey this does produce output in the format I would like however it is not giving me averages for some reason?

Comment: Can you post an example with easy numbers and a small `StarData`? For example: given `StarData = [1 3 4; 1 5 6; 2 3 3]` which result would you get exactly?

Comment: @ImmortalxR But also show what the result should be for that case!

Comment: Okay sorry I hadnt understood exactly what you want, but I posted a better example now.

Comment: @ImmortalxR Huh? I am getting a third value of `1526.3` (i.e. (742+1940+1897)/3), not `463068`. Please copy my code again as currently appears in my answer and try

Comment: @Lusi Mendo I tried again and still no luck, am going to post a full set for one ID and you can see if it works for you.

Comment: @ImmortalxR You must be doing something different than I am doing. With your latest sample I get: averages(1)= 2141865, averages(2)= 0.0046, averages(3)=1905.3, which are correct. Are you _sure_ you are using the code as is _now_ in the answer? Delete your code and copy from scratch

Comment: I am posting the code in my OP exactly as I have it because even using the output I gave you with a clean copy of your code is not working on my end.

Comment: @ImmortalxR The problem must be in `StarData` then. Can you add `disp(StarData)` after the `evalin` line and post the result?

Comment: @ImmortalxR Also, are you declaring `averages` as `global` in your base workspace?

Comment: Yea I am declaring averages as global in the workspace as well, and I will post what I am getting in  the OP

Comment: Please see edit at the end of my answer. I am defining `StarData` within your function and I get the correct result. Try it and tell me

Comment: I used the exact same code as you have posted above and sorry to say but I am not getting the correct values still, same incorrect value as before. I have an exact copy/paste of what you posted.

Comment: Please see updated edit. I have removed the function. Restart Matlab, paste code on command window and see `averages`

Comment: I tried your last suggestion and still my values are wrong, it is the weirdest thing at this point, by any chance would a different matlab version matter because I am using matlab r2013a

Comment: I use 2010b. Do you have access to a lower version? Weird indeed

Comment: @ImmortalxR It seems that `unique` has changed in 2013a (see http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html). Try replacing second line to `[~, ii, jj] = unique(value_sort,'legacy');`

Comment: @ImmortalxR Glad to hear that! So the changed behaviour of `unique` is to blame. I will add an update in this answer.

Comment: @ImmortalxR I also suggest that you clean up your question by removing everything under "Thanks for any help given", as that would mostly confuse future readers