# For each integer, take the mean of all the values

Tags: matlab

I have a question for a problem I am trying to solve.

I have a rather large array with a series of numbers ranging from 4, 4.2,4.4 and 16, 16.5, 16.7 and so on in column 1 and a series of 0s and 1s in column 2 corresponding to each number such that column 1 will be say 5 and column 2 will be say 0. Below is a very small version of the matrix I am working with:

```
[5,0;5.10000000000000,0;5.20000000000000,0;5.25000000000000,0;5.30000000000000,0;5.35000000000000,0;5.45000000000000,0;5.50000000000000,0;5.55000000000000,0;5.60000000000000,0;14.2000000000000,0;5.70000000000000,0;5.80000000000000,0;5.90000000000000,0;14.0000000000000,0;14.9500000000000,1;14.8500000000000,1;14.6000000000000,1;14.3500000000000,1;14.3000000000000,1;14.2500000000000,1;14.3500000000000,1;14.2500000000000,1;14.1500000000000,1;14.0500000000000,1;]
```

What I want to do is write code that averages the 0s and 1s of column 2 for each integer in column 1. I honestly have no idea where to begin, I started to write a for loop, but was unsure of how I would execute a a process on a group of rows in column 2 on the basis of a group of rows in column 1. Does anyone have any ideas? I apologize  I do not have any example code just yet, I honestly have no idea what to do at this point.

Comment: Question is not very clear to me. Can you please provide desired output on your sample input? `What I want to do is write code that averages the 0s and 1s of column 2 for each integer in column 1` ?? column 1 has floating point and how you ant to average?

Comment: You say "for each integer in column 1", but column 1 does not contain integers. Do you mean the integer part? Or do you mean "for each number in column 1"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the average of all values of the second column that have the same integer part in the first column.

You can achieve this by a slight modification of the answer to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363829/matlab-matching-first-column-of-a-row-as-index-and-then-averaging-all-columns-in). Let `x` be your data (2 columns, arbitrary number of rows). Then:

```
x1_int = floor(x(:,1));
[value_sort ind_sort] = sort(x1_int);
[~, ii, jj] = unique(value_sort);
n = diff([0; ii]);
result = [ x1_int(ii) accumarray(jj,x(ind_sort,2))./n ];
```

If you use Matlab 2013a or newer, replace third line by the following. This is necessary because the `unique` function has been changed in Matlab 2013a:

```
[~, ii, jj] = unique(value_sort,'legacy');
```

The variable `result` contains in its column 1 the integer part of column 1 of `x`, and in its column 2 the corresponding average of column 2 of `x`. With your example data:

```
x= [5.0000         0
    5.1000         0
    5.2000         0
    5.2500         0
    5.3000         0
    5.3500         0
    5.4500         0
    5.5000         0
    5.5500         0
    5.6000         0
   14.2000         0
    5.7000         0
    5.8000         0
    5.9000         0
   14.0000         0
   14.9500    1.0000
   14.8500    1.0000
   14.6000    1.0000
   14.3500    1.0000
   14.3000    1.0000
   14.2500    1.0000
   14.3500    1.0000
   14.2500    1.0000
   14.1500    1.0000
   14.0500    1.0000]
```

the result is

```
result =

    5.0000         0
   14.0000    0.8333
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
integers = floor(inputMatrix(:,1));
uniqueIntegers = unique(integers);
K = numel(uniqueIntegers);

outputMean = nan(1,K);
for k = 1:K
    outputMean(k) = mean(inputMatrix(integers==uniqueIntegers(k),2)));
end
```

where inputMatrix is your matrix above. In plain English, convert the first column to integers with the `floor` function, pick out the unique values, and then loop through the unique values and find the mean using logical indexing. The two vectors `uniqueIntegers` and `outputMean` contain those integers and the averaged values of the second column, respectively.

As suggested in comments, I think there are a few ways to read the question. First, as answered above, the OP wants to average together everything that with a 5 to the left of the decimal place.

If, however, the OP wants to average together only those values that contain a 5 (or other integer), then replace the value in the loop with:

```
outputMean(k) = mean(inputMatrix(inputMatrix(:,1)==uniqueIntegers(k),2)));
```

If, however, the OP wants to average together all values that contain an integer, regardless of what the value is, then the entire code block can be reduced to:

```
integers = floor(inputMatrix(:,1)) == inputMatrix(:,1);
outputMean = mean(inputMatrix(integers,2));
```

Comment: Makes sense, but the posted matrix makes no sense since all values in column 1 are unique...

Comment: OP said he wanted to average over the each integer in column 1, that's why I included the `floor` statement to round all the values down.

Comment: I see.  I wouldn't have assumed floor, but it makes sense this way.  +1

Comment: There are at least three ways to read the question by my count. I've added answers to the other two.